# How to prove that admissible/consistent heuristics in A* searching method would lead to optimal solution?

Tags: graph-algorithm, a-star

we have proved in class that if A* in Tree-Search is optimal, then h(n) is admissible(Admissible Heuristics). If using A* in Graph-Search finds the optimal solution, then h(n) is consistent. We proved the properties of admissible and consistent if we assume that A* can find the optimal solution. This indicates that consistent /admissible are necessary conditions for optimality in Graph/Tree Searching.

However, I am not too sure how to prove that they are also both sufficient conditions as well. I tried to figure it out, but I still could not find a good way to prove it. For example, I am not too sure how to prove that being admissible can lead to optimality in Tree-Searching using A*? And similarly, how to prove that being consistent can lead to optimality in Graph-Searching using A*? Thank you in advance!

This is my first time asking on StackOverflow, sorry if I am not phrasing my question well. : )Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would the graph-search proof not apply to a tree-search (since a tree is a particular kind of graph)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment!  I have proved that admissible and consistent are both necessary conditions for tree/graph searching. However, I am confused that how can we prove that they are sufficient conditions that lead to optimality.

Comment: _"we have proved in class that if h(n) is admissible, then using A\* in Tree-Search is optimal"_ - _"I am not too sure how to prove that being admissible can lead to optimality in Tree-Searching using A\*"_ - ???

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Ohh, sorry. I made a careless mistake. I have just fixed the question now. Thanks for pointing it out. : )

Answer (score 1):

> This indicates that consistent /admissible are necessary conditions for optimality in Graph/Tree Searching.

No, it implies they're **sufficient** conditions. In fact, the converse is not true - it is possible to find cases where a given non-admissible heuristic returns the optimal result for a specific graph *(simple counter-example: a tree with only one path will return the optimal path for any heuristic)*.  Thus they are not **necessary** conditions.

As a side note, 'consistent' implies 'admissible', and trees are a type of graph, so it is enough to prove the "admissible + graph" case, and all four cases (admissible/consistent, tree/graph) are immediately implied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think indeed they should not be necessary conditions according to your counter-example mentioned above. But I am still a little curious and could u pls give me some hints on how to prove that they are sufficient conditions?

Comment: Hi, to add on, I found a little possible flaw in the counterexample mentioned in the answer. I think that Optimality of algorithms means that an algorithm can always find an optimal solution in any graphs. However, in the counterexample mentioned above, it specifies only one type of graph, where non-optimal algorithms like BFS or DFS can also find the optimal path in a single-path tree mentioned above. Thus, I think that it might not be a very suitable counterexample here.

Comment: @Leonard: Yes, we're talking about all graphs. However to disprove a statement about all graphs, you only need to find one counter-example. The statement here is from your question, _"If using A\* in Graph-Search finds the optimal solution, then h(n) is consistent"_, which is false. The fact that BFS and DFS find the same path is irrelevant.